# I'm trying to directly connect to the Tor Network but when i click connect it just loads forever and doesn't connect

Tags: connection

```
7/7/2017 15:33:39 PM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
7/7/2017 15:33:39 PM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
7/7/2017 15:33:39 PM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
7/7/2017 15:33:39 PM.000 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
7/7/2017 15:33:39 PM.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network 
7/7/2017 15:33:39 PM.300 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop 0 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
7/7/2017 15:33:39 PM.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop 
7/7/2017 15:33:40 PM.300 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop 0 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
7/7/2017 15:33:41 PM.300 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop 0 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
7/7/2017 15:33:42 PM.300 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop 0 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
7/7/2017 15:33:43 PM.300 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop 0 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
7/7/2017 15:33:44 PM.300 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop 0 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
7/7/2017 15:33:45 PM.300 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop 0 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
7/7/2017 15:33:46 PM.300 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop 0 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
7/7/2017 15:33:47 PM.300 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop 0 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
7/7/2017 15:33:47 PM.800 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
7/7/2017 15:33:47 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
7/7/2017 15:33:47 PM.800 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
7/7/2017 15:33:48 PM.300 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Comment: Which version of Tor Browser are you using?